# SAP method freezes

Tags: java, collision-detection, aabb

When I run this method in game the code freezes.

Here are the methods:

```
public static void sort(List<EndPoint> axis,int ax) {
    for(int j = 1; j < axis.size();j++) {
        EndPoint keyelement = axis.get(j);
        float key = keyelement.getValue();

        int i = j - 1;

        while(i >= 0 && axis.get(i).getValue() > key) {
            EndPoint swapper = axis.get(i);


            //TODO check bounding boxes
            AABB aabb = AABB.getAABB(swapper);
            AABB aabb1 = AABB.getAABB(keyelement);
            if(intersects(AABB.getAABB(swapper), AABB.getAABB(keyelement),ax)) {
                if(intersects(aabb,aabb1)){
                    System.out.println("Collision "+ aabb + " : " + aabb1);
                    PairManager.addPair(aabb, aabb1);
                }
            }

            axis.add(i + 1, swapper);
            i--; 
        }
        axis.add(i + 1, keyelement);

    }
}

public static void updateObjects() {
    sort(xaxis,0);
    sort(yaxis,1);
    sort(zaxis,2);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to see what is happening? Also why are you calling the method *sort* if in fact are you *adding* elements to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you get to the end of this loop:

`for(int j = 1; j < axis.size();j++) {`

you add to the axis:

`axis.add(i + 1, keyelement);`

I didn't see any place that you ever remove elements from `axis`. Since it gains at least one element on every iteration & are iterating one element at a time, you can't ever process all of the elements.

As suggested by @Wondra - you should add some break points to the code, run the debugger & step through the lines one at a time to see how the execution of your code does & does not match what your intent.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you is to place [break points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-to-use-breakpoints-in-eclipse) in your code to determine what is making your application freeze, I do however, get the feeling that you might be iterating through your loop incorrectly. Without further information I can't really say much else.